# Future of Flex in Apache

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, html, air, flash-builder

I am a Flex developer. I think Flash builder is a great development environment for developing rich internet applications , 3D games, etc.

Now I am worried about the latest news related to Flex. Some blogs and news wrote flex is going to die. Another one wrote flex has not died.

How can I know latest updates about Flex in Apache. I am visiting Apache incubator site about Flex daily

- http://incubator.apache.org/flex/
- http://blogs.apache.org/flex/.

But  I didn't get a satisfying answer. I read many articles I found with google search. I'm a little confused about the future of flex. I don't know how I can develop applications in HTML5 instead of Flex. I think it is too difficult. I can't develop big rich applications using html5 like www.pixlr.com, dashboard applications , Flash 3D games etc. Html5 is concept with oops?

I also have some more questions.

Why did adobe abandon flex?
What progressions will happen in Apache incubator for flex
What is real future of flex in Rich Internet Applications World?
In stack overflow, there is lot of specialists, developers and researchers .So I think stack overflow is a good place to ask these questions.
I expect this should be helpful for all Flex programmers. 
Please help.

Comment: This is really not a good question to ask on SO: It will likely lead to a lengthy discussion with lots of guesses and opinions, instead of facts. If you're interested in the future of Flex, see the flex blog at http://blogs.apache.org/flex/ , or join one of the mailing lists: http://incubator.apache.org/flex/mailing-lists.html

Comment: There is also a status page where you can get all the other info: http://incubator.apache.org/projects/flex.html This also includes a link to the SVN repo where you can get the source code and keep track with all the changes.

Comment: thanks wetraumpirat for your comment. I post this qustions for not long discussion. just know fact about current status of flex

Comment: I realize that was your intent - still, the choice of topic alone is likely to produce a result like that.  Just look at the first answer you got: It is everything a good answer at SO should **not** be.

Comment: Please mark as Community Wiki?

Comment: If you are not good at English, I can understand that, but you could at least try to make less typing errors. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Adobe "abandons" Flex because of the difficulty to maintain the flash player on mobile multi-platforms. You can't have the flash player plugin, and generally plugins, installed everywhere : it asks a lot of efforts to make it work on every device.

Today, thanks to ios (and android) popularity, everything is application based. I just think that, naturally, Air is the best technology to work with, since it produces platform dependant executables with platform independant source code.

Since they don't have the time to keep on raising Flex, they give it to the Apache community, which have great projects like the HTTP Server.

Well, probably, HTML5 will be best in the future. Or not. HTML5 is a community language, Flex had a private owner. But now, Flex is free of his private owner, so it will naturally compete with HTML5.

At the moment, it is stable, mature, and the best RIA choice.
I think Flex has a great future.
But that's just my point of view :)

Comment: It's just your opinion, that's right - and therefore it should not be an *answer*, but a *comment*.  That is exactly the problem with questions like this one: There is no way to actually answer them.

Comment: I agree there may not be an answer for it, then we just not mark it as answered. Anyway this post concentrates a lot of popular question from most flex developers, and at least we could check what are others opinions. I agree with Nimaen, so I will vote him up. Btw, writing an answer in this case is the best option: since people like me and you (weltraumpirat) can comment and vote up and down.

Comment: Indeed, but in these kinds of questions, there are as much answers as people in the world :)
So, posting an answer or comment is probably the same.
I tried to post something constructive, that's why I posted an answer, not a comment ^^

Comment: It's simply not a fit for Stack Overflow's Question & Answer format. just read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Just today became clear that actually Adobe plans for Flash platforms is not shorter than 10 years from now on. Adobe AIR will continue to expand over all mobile platforms and TV's. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html Flex on other side will be fully supported for 5 more years as it is , and after then the cumunity shall test units itself, which means that if things get the right way Flex will be never abandoned, actually the oposite. Flash and Flex goin hand by hand into observeable future. This is just side turn to save some coin in Adobe.